# What is the assignment-expression in array brackets in C?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

In C89 A.1.2.2 Declarations

> direct-declarator [  constant-expression ]

In C99 A.2.2 Declarations

> direct-declarator [ type-qualifier-list_opt assignment-expression_opt ]

I understand `assignment-expression_opt` as `var = 1;`. But arrays are not declared like `int arr[i = 0];`. Why does C99 use the term "assignment-expression" instead of "constant-expression"and what does it mean?

Comment: Variadic-length arrays can be declared like that, so that's why the wider class, I guess (constant expressions are effectively a subset of assignment expressions). Keep in mind that `4` or `x ? a : b` are also grammatically reducible to assignment expressions in the right contexts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C89 there was no support for variable length arrays.  This means that array sizes must be fixed at compile time.

Starting with C99, declarations and statements may be mixed within a block, so full expressions that must be executed are now allowed as an initializer.  This also is what allows for variable length arrays to be created.

So a declaration like `int arr[i=0];` is valid syntax, although it's invalid because it created an array of size 0.  `int arr[i=2];` is valid and will create `arr` as an array of `int` of size 2, and it sets `i` to 2.

Answer (score 4):

This is because C99 supports VLA and whatever goes between `[]` may then be pretty much any expression.

As for why it says *assignment-expression* specifically:

The way the syntax of expressions and operator precedence is described in C, is by having each operator group's syntax point at the operator group with higher precedence than itself. For example look at the syntax for an assignment expression:

> *assignment-expression:*
> *conditional-expression*

It points at the conditional `?:` operator which will be the next operator group with higher precedence than assignment operators.

And for the comma operator with lowest precedence of all, the syntax is actually:

> *expression:*
> *assignment-expression*
> *expression* `,` *assignment-expression*

That is, the syntax for an expression in C. Now for some reason, C99 apparently didn't want to allow comma operators inside `[]`. I don't know why - perhaps it would make qualified/static array parameter declarators too strange. So instead of using *expression* in the *direct-declarator* syntax, they picked the next operator group above the comma operator, the assignment operators.

Comment: maybe because some languages use `A[x,y]` syntax to access 2d arrays while C requires  `A[x][y]`. It may result in difficult to spot errors.